# how to add project jar into eclipseworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\serverfolder\projectfolder\web-inf\lib

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2

i am using Eclipse IDE. i have a maven projects as lmexadapter-core-api, lmexadapter-core-impl, lmex-moodle-api, lmexserver-mobile-api, lmexadapter-moodle-api, lmexadapter-moodle-impl. i have  dependency in pom as below :

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>lmexadapter-moodle</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter</groupId>
    <artifactId>lmexadapter-moodle-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Maven Webapp Archetype</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>lmexadapter-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>lmexadapter-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.server.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>lmexserver-mobile-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle</groupId>
            <artifactId>lmexadapter-moodle-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle</groupId>
            <artifactId>lmexadapter-moodle-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

i am using tomcat as my application server. i get all the jar except lmexadapter-moodle-api, lmexadapter-moodle-impl in my D:\EclipseWorskpace\ew-pg\lmexadapter.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\lmexadapter-moodle-web\WEB-INF\lib.  because of this application is unable to locate class of lmexadapter-moodle-impl. what should i have to define so it will take both jar in a specified path as above.

please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using m2eclipse with wtp support enabled?  If not, you can try doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming current version of Eclipse and Maven plugin, is this something that can be solved by adding Maven dependencies to "project deployment assembly"? 
If you have your project configured as Dynamic Web Project and Tomcat as server in Eclipse, this is under Project->Deployment Assembly->Add->java build path entries -> Maven dependencies.